Were Ham and his descendants cursed?
It is narrated in The History of al-Tabari Al-Tabari, Vol. 2, p. 11, p. 11:

It is related that Noah prayed that Ham's color would be changed and that his descendants would be slaves to the children of Shem and Japheth."

It is narrated in The History of al-Tabari Al-Tabari, Al-Tabari, Vol. 2, p. 21, p. 21:

"It is related by the father of Damrah b. Rabi'ah-Ibn 'Ata' that Ham begat all those who are black and curly-haired, while Japheth begat all those who are full-faced with small eyes, and Shem begat everyone who is handsome of face with beautiful hair. Noah prayed that the hair of Ham's descendants would not grow beyond their ears, and that wherever his descendants met the children of Shem, the latter would enslave them."

What is the authenticity of these narrations? Likewise, are there any authentic passages within the Islamic discourse that relate a message that African folks are destined to be enslaved and cursed?

Can you please provide your reference to the specific passage so that I can find the quote?

@Syed It's on page 21 of William Brinner's translation of The History of al-Tabari (تاريخ الرسل والملوك) Vol. 2.

I edited the following post and included citations for each passage. If you know the answer, please do relay it. Thank you.

Okay, so as for the hadith you have mentioned. it is classified as da'if (I.e., weak) by Darussalam. It's on the same site you added the link of. As for your references, I will have a look at them today and run around a bit to some people to learn if they hold any weight.

Albani (Darussalam) is not a credible source for gradings.

Ask one focused question per post.

@ShubuhatExcess It is. Plenty of non-salafi scholars except it. While I do agree that he rahimahullah had his own mistakes and the Salafis might have mistakes in their hadith gradings, it does not in and of itself make them unreliable. It is more of a case-by-case basis. I'd rather accept a Salafi grading in cases I am not able to find a non-salafi grading that contradicts with it rather than throwing them completely out of the equation. Anyhow, the answer by UmH should suffice. If I find anything of value that is not present in it, I will add my own answer as well, or perhaps edit it.

I meant *accept. Sorry, can't edit my comment anymore.

The report about Noah (عليه السلام) cursing Ham because he did not cover his nakedness and that being the cause of his skin color changing to black is not authentic. The chain of the report does not go up to the Prophet ﷺ and is likely part of the part of the Israelite traditions which the people heard from the People of the Book.
The report has been classed as Daee'f in the grading of Tarikh Tabari by Muhammad bin Tahir. Ibn al-Jawzi has stated that nothing of such stories is proven nor authentic. Suyooti has stated that the hadith about the color being due to the clay is more deserving to be relied upon regarding the reason for the color.
Ref: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/408580/

What about the other narrations in my question. Why were they deleted?

@ShubuhatExcess I assume it's because of that hadith not having to do anything with the question directly. It doesn't have to do anything with the children of Ham being cursed or not. It only states that the Ethiopians are children of ham, nothing else. So I can't really see how it adds much to the question itself, even more so considering that it's da'eef.
